# What is Multiple key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, key

Can anybody explain that what is multiple key in terms of mysql?

whether it is combination of columns as primary key or indexed column?

Comment: search google for 'composite keys'

Answer (score 0):

there can be multiple keys (that is several keys) on a table to speed up different types of queries. Some of the keys can be multiple column keys (composite keys)